# Graph or its Complement contains a triangle.

Tags: graph-theory, ramsey-theory

How do I prove that the graph with at least 6 vertices or its complement contains a triangle?

Do I have to prove that if a graph contains a triangle, then its complement doesn't contain, and the opposite if its complement contains a triange then a graph doesn't?

Comment: No.  If the graph contains a triangle, you are done. If it doesn't, then prove that its complement does.

Comment: Won't you please give me a hint? I have no idea how to prove that.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be slightly easier to think about if you formulate it as

> Color each edge in $K_6$ either red or green. Then there at least one triangle that is all red or all green.

(This is really the same as "arbitrary graph on 6 vertices", where "red" means an edge that's there and "green" means one that isn't -- but it makes it a bit easier to think about "edge is there" and "edge isn't there" as symmetric cases).

And a proof could go somewhat like:

- Choose three vertices $1$, $2$ and $3$. If the edges $12$, $23$ and $31$ all have the same color, then we're done. Otherwise let's say without loss of generality that $12$ and $23$ are red and $31$ is green.
- Now consider a fourth vertex $4$. If $14$ and $34$ are both green, then $134$ is a green triangle. So assume one of them is red. If $24$ is now red then $124$ or $234$ is a red triangle. So the only way *not* to have a valid triangle yet is if $24$ is green.

... and so forth.

Comment: Can't we simply prove this without the knowledge of colouring?

Comment: @hasi: Which "knowledge of coloring" is it you speak about? You can think of patterns instead, or make some edges thin and others thick if you have some kind of aversion to colors -- but I'd say most of us learned enough about colored lines to follow this proof while playing with crayons in kindergarden.

Comment: I don't know yet what the coloring is. So I thought this will require a simlier prove.

Comment: @hasi: The point of the proof is to show that _no matter how you color the edges_, there will be a triangle where all three edges have the same color. You don't need to be told which coloring to use -- the proof works with ALL colorings.

Answer (score 1):

So probably the reason this was tagged with 'ramsey-theory' is [this section of the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem#Example:_R.283.2C_3.29_.3D_6) :

> In the 2-colour case, an arbitrary simple graph G = (V, E) can be identified with the complete graph on the vertex set V whose edges are coloured with two colours (all the edges corresponding to those in E receive one colour and all the other edges receive the other colour.)

and then:

> Conversely, it is possible to 2-colour a K5 without creating any monochromatic K3, showing that R(3, 3) > 5. The unique colouring is shown to the right. Thus R(3, 3) = 6.

Consider, for example the 6-cycle (C6). Obviously it has no triangles - now what is the complement of C6? Try drawing the complete graph on 6 vertices (K6) and coloring it with one color for C6 and another for the rest of the edges (the complement) - does this have a triangle?

Comment: This task doesn't require knowledge of colouring. And I'm sure in that because we haven't yet studied that paragraph but this question is included in the questionnaire.

Comment: @hasi Fair enough. Perhaps someone else will have a simpler proof. I think also your question might be better worded as : *any* graph on at least 6 vertices either has a triangle or its complement does.

Comment: Ah, I see now ( I found a proof elsewhere) : all you need to prove is that for any graph >5 there is a set of 3 vertices that are disconnected or in a triangle. If they are disconnected in G then they are a triangle in G' (the complement)

Comment: That makes sense but still isn't totally clear. Could you please share the link of your proof